# NSURLSession background upload not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-process

I'm trying to upload a series of files from iPhone up to a server, with the intent that the upload of these files happen even when the App is in the background or suspended.

I'm using **background transfer** provided by `NSURLSession` and its series of APIs.

**what was odd was it it was fully working 2 weeks ago**. As in:

1. I would click the "upload" button on the UI
2. files would start to appear one by one on my server
3. I tap the "Home" button on the iPhone to make the app go into the background
4. Files would continue to upload to the server until it all completes

Last couple of days, I've been doing some refactoring outside of the network module. When I tried the upload again a couple of days ago, as soon as I hit "Home" button, step (3) above. File upload would stop, when I go into the app again. Upload would resume.

*It's as if background upload isn't even working (for one file, let alone multiple files).*

I've ran the code multiple times, and found about 1 / 50 times it works. But the other 49 times it doesn't. I've also checked out the version of the code that used to work (both server + iOS), and it no longer works - or rather, works vary rarely (the 1/50)

Having gone through the [rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html) for Background transfer and [Lifecycle of URL Session](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/NSURLSessionConcepts/NSURLSessionConcepts.html) multiple times to make sure I'm adhering by Apple suggested guidelines, I'm racking my brain as to what broke, it boggles the mind how illogical this is - **I suspect it's something other than code implementation.**

So any help is appreciated...

### Implementation

1) In `init` method for my network class (a singleton), I initialise the `NSURLSessionConfiguration` and `NSURLSession`:

```
    urlSessionConfigUpload = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:kBACKGROUND_SESSION_CONFIG_ID];
    urlSessionConfigUpload.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = YES;
    urlSessionConfigUpload.discretionary = YES;
    urlSessionConfigUpload.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 8;
    urlSessionConfigUpload.networkServiceType = NSURLNetworkServiceTypeBackground;
    urlSessionConfigUpload.HTTPShouldUsePipelining = NO; 
    urlSessionConfigUpload.allowsCellularAccess = NO;

    urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:urlSessionConfigUpload delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
```

2) There's a convenience method called to do the actual upload. There is only ever 1 upload task per session:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
    [urlRequest addValue:@"keep-alive" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];
    [urlRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    // NB: for upload task in the background, uploadTaskWithRequest:fromData (explicit construction of HTTP POST body) can’t be used,
    // must use uploadTaskWithRequest:fromFile (requiring HTTP PUT)
    NSURLSessionDataTask *uploadTask = [urlSession uploadTaskWithRequest:urlRequest fromFile:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
    [uploadTask resume];
```

3) In the `didCompleteWithError` delegate, I check if all files have been uploaded, if not, move onto the next file - `GLOBAL.uploadQueue` is where I keep a reference to all files I have to upload, `GLOBAL.uploadQueueIndexNextFile`

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
        didCompleteWithError:(nullable NSError *)error
{
    if ((error == nil && (GLOBAL.uploadQueueIndexNextFile < GLOBAL.uploadQueue.count - 1)) {
        // Not on last file, increment counter, start upload of next file
        speedLoggerResult = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Transferring %i of %i files", (GLOBAL.uploadQueueIndexNextFile + 1), GLOBAL.uploadQueue.count];
        GLOBAL.uploadQueueIndexNextFile++; 
        [GLOBAL.fileProcessor processNextFileInUploadQueue];
    }
}
```

`processNextFileInUploadQueue` will prepare the file and call the convenience method for upload ((2) above).

Here are some sample output from caveman debugging (for file 2 - 4). **Notice, how as soon as app goes into background, upload stops.**

*Note, I've also waited longer than the 10 seconds shown in the output below. Longest was I left for dinner (30 minutes), came back and the upload ended up timing out. The OS never picked it up once the app is in the background.*

```
2016-02-21 05:53:01 +0000 | bkgd debug - about to start upload task | queueIndex: 2

2016-02-21 05:53:01 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 32768 of 233546 | queueIndex: 2

2016-02-21 05:53:01 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 65536 of 233546 | queueIndex: 2

2016-02-21 05:53:01 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 98304 of 233546 | queueIndex: 2

2016-02-21 05:53:01 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 131072 of 233546 | queueIndex: 2

2016-02-21 05:53:01 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 163840 of 233546 | queueIndex: 2

2016-02-21 05:53:01 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 196608 of 233546 | queueIndex: 2

2016-02-21 05:53:01 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 229376 of 233546 | queueIndex: 2

2016-02-21 05:53:01 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 233546 of 233546 | queueIndex: 2

2016-02-21 05:53:01 +0000 | in networking | didCompleteWithError | queueindex: 2

bkgd debug - processing next file

2016-02-21 05:53:02 +0000 | bkgd debug - about to start upload task | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:02 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 32768 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:02 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 65536 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:02 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 98304 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:02 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 131072 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:02 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 163840 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:02 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 196608 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:02 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 229376 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:02 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 262144 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:02 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 294912 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:02 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 327680 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:02 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 360448 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:02 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 387704 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:02 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 391392 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:02 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 393216 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:02 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 425984 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:02 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 458752 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:02 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 491520 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:02 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 524288 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:02 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 538768 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:03 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 541664 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:03 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 550352 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:03 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 553248 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:03 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 557056 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:03 +0000 | App went into background.

2016-02-21 05:53:03 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 564832 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:03 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 567728 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:03 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 582208 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:14 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 585104 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:14 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 589824 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:14 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 621680 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:14 +0000 | App came into foreground. 

2016-02-21 05:53:14 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 622592 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:14 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 655360 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:14 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 688128 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:14 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 720896 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:14 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 753664 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:14 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 786432 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:14 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 819200 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:15 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 851968 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:15 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 884736 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:15 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 887632 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:15 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 893424 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:15 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 917504 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:15 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 939224 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:15 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 950272 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:15 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 970544 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:15 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 983040 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:15 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 1015808 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:15 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 1048576 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:15 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 1081344 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:15 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 1114112 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:15 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 1146880 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:15 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 1179648 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:15 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 1212416 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:15 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 1231286 of 1231286 | queueIndex: 3

2016-02-21 05:53:16 +0000 | in networking | didCompleteWithError | queueindex: 3

bkgd debug - processing next file

2016-02-21 05:53:16 +0000 | bkgd debug - about to start upload task | queueIndex: 4

2016-02-21 05:53:16 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 32768 of 1278039 | queueIndex: 4

2016-02-21 05:53:16 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 65536 of 1278039 | queueIndex: 4

2016-02-21 05:53:16 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 98304 of 1278039 | queueIndex: 4

2016-02-21 05:53:16 +0000 | in networking | totalBytesSent | 131072 of 1278039 | queueIndex: 4
```

Happy to try anything at this point. Thanks!

### EDIT #1

Observed when background upload does work `application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:` is called by the OS. Invariably that call back is never made when it doesn't work.

I'm not sure if a prerequisite for background upload is the OS must kill the App first. If so, under what conditions does that happen? And can we prompt it?

As mentioned 49 times out of 50, OS will keep the app in the background, and upload is halted.

Comment: Did you make changes to background modes? Is your app using background tasks? Have you tried setting `discretionary` to `NO`? Are you connected using Wi-Fi (without Wi-Fi Assist), and is the device plugged in? Of course, you're testing this on an actual device and not the simulator?

Comment: I'm using background tasks (see session configuration code). Have tried setting `discretionary` to `NO` - Apple's doc also says if a new task is started in the background it will ignore `discretionary` setting, and just use `YES`. All tests were ran on device, on wifi.  What do you mean by "make changes to background modes"?

Comment: By background tasks I mean those you start with `UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`. By background modes, I mean those that are set in `UIBackgroundModes` (or via the Background modes sections of the Capabilities tab of your project).

Comment: I haven't made any changes to background mode. The only code catering to background processing are outlined in my OP. Thx

Comment: You do have only one background session configuration and session (via a singleton), right?

Comment: The session config (only 1), and session (only 1) objects are initialised as part of the singleton network object.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all methods of the delegate except for the `didCompleteWithError:`? The `urlSession` you use when creating the uploadTask is really the same you created in `init`? Have you checked that background app refresh is not disabled in Settings for your app? Not sure if it would affect background uploads, but just in case...

Comment: Also, is there any different between the first upload and subsequent uploads? Have you tried rebooting the device just in case the background upload daemon is in a weird state? Have you checked the device's logs (not just the app's)? Do background uploads work in other apps?

Comment: Has anything else changed in the past few weeks?  Changes to your network connection that is causing the uploads to go slower? Changes to the server's configuration or load?  Given that you said the old version that used to work doesn't now, I think it may be something external to the code.

Comment: @snowbound facing exactly same issue. How did you come out of this?

Answer (score 3):

There is one thing wanted to make it clear is you cannot keep running in background any task for long, as Apple doesn't allows you. In only special cases Apple consider it. Best explained in [Running background services in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417837/running-background-services-in-ios?rq=1)

Now coming back to your question issue with your implementation is it will only work in background for upload task which are initiated when app was active and still task is not complete. Thats the reason for 1 in 50 attempts you see task is working in background.

Now to solve your issue you have to initiate all/bunch of upload at once so that incase if app goes in background still your app will be able upload files. This briliant [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/background-transfer-service-ios7/) explain different cases related to Background Transfer.

Also you can try out [AFNetworking](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/3.0.4/) multipart request for upload.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://example.com/upload" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file://path/to/image.jpg"] name:@"file" fileName:@"filename.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg" error:nil];
    } error:nil];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
uploadTask = [manager
              uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request
              progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
                  // This is not called back on the main queue.
                  // You are responsible for dispatching to the main queue for UI updates
                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                      //Update the progress view
                      [progressView setProgress:uploadProgress.fractionCompleted];
                  });
              }
              completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                  if (error) {
                      NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                  } else {
                      NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);
                  }
              }];

[uploadTask resume];
```

Answer (score 3):

I was into similar problem, the files were uploading in foreground. It stopped while in the background.

After having spent couple of days in reviewing the documentation and similar answers.[This solution worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33786926/1453691/)

1. `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier` is one of the important property which would be very useful.
   Create this in app delegate class and initialise it to `UIBackgroundTaskInvalid` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

--

```
@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (atomic) UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSTimer *timer;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    return YES;
}
```

2. While the app is transitioning it's state from Foreground to Background or vice versa. We need to ensure to check this property in it's relevant delegate methods.

> beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler
>   is Very Crucial for this to actually start the background Task in the background.

--

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    self.bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        if (self.bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.bgTask];
            self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        }
    }];

    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(startTracking) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // invalidate the timer if still running

    [self.timer invalidate];

    // end the background task if still present

    if (self.bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.bgTask];
        self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }
}
```

**You can debug the code in real device and check it in proper network conditions.**

3. Also, you can add the below delegate method to keep track of the bytesSent.

--

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
              task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
   didSendBodyData:(int64_t)bytesSent
    totalBytesSent:(int64_t)totalBytesSent
totalBytesExpectedToSend:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToSend
{
    // Periodically informs the delegate of the progress of sending body content to the server.

    // Compute progress percentage
    float progress = (float)totalBytesSent / (float)totalBytesExpectedToSend;

    // Compute time executed so far
    NSDate *stopTime = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval executionTime = [stopTime timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime];

    // Send info to console
    NSLog(@"%s bytesSent = %lld, totalBytesSent: %lld, totalBytesExpectedToSend: %lld, progress %.3f, time (s): %.1f", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, bytesSent, totalBytesSent, totalBytesExpectedToSend, progress*100, executionTime);


}
```

I Hope it helps for someone.

Answer (score 1):

I have also the same concerns in one of my video app. This issue occurs after 14th Feb. I dig a lot and found this occurs after apple has changed their worldwide certificates. Please check this `https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/`.
Solution is to first revoked existing certificates from keychain access and then add new development/distribution certificates, new app id and provisioning profile. It will definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is at the uploading part. You are initiating the next upload task after completing the previous one instead create all the uploading task once. In your appDelegate store the completion handler from `application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:` as a property. Call the completion block in `NSURLSessionDelegate` `URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession:` delegate method of `NSURLSessionDelegate`. Make sure that all the upload tasks are completed before making the call. This tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/background-transfer-service-ios7/ explains well about the downloading task. May be you can apply the same rules for your upload task.